# Why does my query not find the values I pass it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to do my own query in spring to delete something in the database. I pass it some values with `@Param`, java executes the query but with ? instead of the actual value like this:

```
Hibernate: DELETE FROM game_like WHERE player_id=? AND game_id=?
```

Query:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM game_like WHERE player_id=:#{#playerId} AND game_id=:#{#gameId}", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteReference(@Param("playerId") Long player, @Param("gameId") Long game);
```

I have tried different things but nothing is working and I dont understand why this is happening. can someone clarify?

EDIT:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "game_like", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"))
private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Without seeing any code (How the query is defined/called in your own code) it's impossible to give an adequate answer.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS sorry I forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

In order to use parameters on the query you can define it as follow on your repository class:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM game_like WHERE player_id=?1 AND game_id=?2")
void deleteReference(Long player_id, Long game_id);
```

As you can see you don't have to use `@Param`. You just need to use the position of the parameter on your query.

Comment: That gives me this error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.comeon.gamelove.gameLove.gameLove

Comment: Please post on your question how is your entity implemented? I assume it have 2 ids??

Comment: i just create the linking table like i added to the post with yes 2 ids 1 for player and 1 for game. No actual entity

Comment: You seem to be mixin different strategies. This is a many to many relationship right? Why don't you let hibernate handle it? Or, d'ont use relationships at all and create an entity to manage the relationship.

Comment: You just need to delete the items form the list and then update the entity.

Comment: Tried to create an entity but I didn't get that to work because I couldn't find full solution anywhere on how to use it (I tried on my own but in the end my other entities was detached from hibernate and to fix it was too much work that again was poorly explained everywhere). I also tried deleting from the list and using repository.save but that didn't do anything and repository.delete deleted the reference + the entity and as no one on this site wanted to explain and instead tell me to do it another way I went with this approach that in the end actually worked

Comment: But thank you for your help anyway as I solved it in the end!